# Slider background image doesn't look well on Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, responsive, microsoft-edge

I have created a slider on my Wordpress website and it looks just fine on Google chrome, but when I open it on my Microsoft Edge it zooms into the picture making it look huge and pixelated. Is there any CSS code I can add to make background look normal on Microsoft Edge?

```
        <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <div class="elementor-slides-wrapper elementor-slick-slider" dir="ltr">
    <div class="elementor-slides" data-slider_options="{&quot;slidesToShow&quot;:1,&quot;autoplaySpeed&quot;:4000,&quot;autoplay&quot;:true,&quot;infinite&quot;:true,&quot;pauseOnHover&quot;:false,&quot;speed&quot;:500,&quot;arrows&quot;:false,&quot;dots&quot;:false,&quot;rtl&quot;:false,&quot;fade&quot;:true}" data-animation="">
        <div class="elementor-repeater-item-c324989 slick-slide"><div class="slick-slide-bg"></div><div  class="slick-slide-inner"><div class="elementor-background-overlay"></div><div class="elementor-slide-content"><div class="elementor-slide-heading"><font dir="rtl"><font color="#ed6524">שוב</font> הפגישה לא התחילה בזמן?</font></div><div class="elementor-slide-description"><BR><BR></div></div></div></div><div class="elementor-repeater-item-15a3089 slick-slide"><div class="slick-slide-bg"></div><div  class="slick-slide-inner"><div class="elementor-background-overlay"></div><div class="elementor-slide-content"><div class="elementor-slide-heading"><font dir="rtl"><font color="#ed6524">שוב</font> הפגישה לא התחילה בזמן?</font></div><div class="elementor-slide-description"><BR><BR></div></div></div></div><div class="elementor-repeater-item-20784b4 slick-slide"><div class="slick-slide-bg"></div><div  class="slick-slide-inner"><div class="elementor-background-overlay"></div><div class="elementor-slide-content"><div class="elementor-slide-heading"><font dir="rtl"><font color="#ed6524">שוב</font> הפגישה לא התחילה בזמן?</font></div></div></div></div>         </div>
</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is how it looks like on Microsoft Edge:
[image]

And here is how it looks like on Google Chrome with the same screen resolution:
[image]

Here's the website link: [www.naotech.com/video-conference](http://www.naotech.com/video-conference)

Current customized CSS:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)  and (min-width: 414px) {

.elementor-1063 .elementor-element.elementor-element-da9971b .slick-slide-inner
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(28,34,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%) !important;
    background-size: 100%;

}}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 414px) {
.elementor-1063 .elementor-element.elementor-element-fb358d5 .elementor-repeater-item-15a3089 .slick-slide-inner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(28,34,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%) !important;

}}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 414px) {
.elementor-1063 .elementor-element.elementor-element-da9971b .elementor-slide-heading
{
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 1400px) {
.elementor-element .slick-slide-bg{
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center 100%;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you set a `background-size`?

Comment: Requesting a css for this slider

Comment: @SamJohnson and `background-size`, I suppose

Comment: Tried so set it as 100%

Comment: I edited my main post with the current customized CSS.
Btw I also tried to set it as cover and it didn't effect Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the website on my side on Edge(Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0) and Chrome.The website works well on both browsers.

You could see my screenshot:
[image: screenshot of Edge]
[image: screenshot of Chrome]

Maybe the version has affected the result, so I'd like to ask that what version of Edge you're using. If possible, please share your detailed source code so that it will be easier to help you.